# Is it possible to separate a quantum circuit into several small sub circuits and measure individually?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, superconducting-quantum-computing

For example, if I have a BV3 circuit and I execute and measure them together, the results are 100% 111.
[image: original circuit]

[image: original results]

If I separate it into three subcircuits and measure only one qubit each time, the measurement results are all 100% 1. If this phenomenon exists, why do we still have to execute the whole circuit and measure all the qubits? Or is there anything to prevent it happens from a real machine?

[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: You cant do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular circuit doesn't entangle the qubits - during and after its execution the quantum state of the system can be represented as a tensor product of the states of individual qubits. This means that you can indeed break it up into parts and execute them independently.

In general, quantum circuits will entangle the qubits, so such breakdown would change the outcomes of circuit execution.

Answer (score 1):

And to expand on Mariia's answer a little bit... With this equality (to match your left side of the circuit):
[image: equality of X H and H Z]

You can draw the Bernstein-Vazirani circuit like this, the qubits are just not entangled:
[image]